# SCNNode position in different places when image recognized Swift

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, scnnode, arscnview

I have this code in the didAddNode after an image is recognized. 
The images are displaying on top of each other in an X pattern. I need them to be one next to the other. I have tried the SCNNode x, y, and z but the image is not moving within the middle point. I have done the anchor to be the reference image before but that also did not get me to the goal. I tried the SCNVector3(0,0,-0.2) the image disappears off the screen

```
  //IMAGE 1
let plane = SCNPlane(width: 0.01 ,height: 0.01)
            if let cgImage = ImageUse!.cgImage {
                plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = cgImage
            }
let overlayNode = SCNNode.init(geometry: plane)
                      overlayNode.eulerAngles.x = -Float.pi / 2
                      node.addChildNode(overlayNode)

//IMAGE 2
let plane2 = SCNPlane(width: 0.01,height: 0.01)

if let cgImage = ImageUse2!.cgImage {
              plane2.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = cgImage
               }

let overlayNode2 = SCNNode.init(geometry: plane2)
            overlayNode2.eulerAngles.x = -Float.pi / 4
            node.addChildNode(overlayNode2)
```

Here what is showing up:

[image]

This is my goal:

[image]

Comment: For future readers and better readability, please add your solution in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got the image node to be placed on how I need it. I had to play around with overlayNode2.position = SCNVector3(-0.01, -0.01, -0.01) overlayNode2.eulerAngles.x = -Float.pi / 2